# How may I rename variables in a df using gsub()?

Tags: gsub

I am trying to rename taxa annotations in an abundance matrix for bubble plot creation (Original data 16S MiSeq).  My data frame "data_melt" is shown below:

[image]

And I am looking to rename the taxa IDs in the "variable" column to simply the last name (class level).  For example: "D_0__Archaea.D_1__Altiarchaeota.D_2__Altiarchaeia" to "Altiarchaeia".

I have attempted

```
data_melt$variable <- gsub("D_0__[A-z].D_1__[A-z].D_2__", "", data_melt$variable)
```

with no avail.  I have used this line of code on other datasets successfully, but there is no change to "data_melt".  There aren't even any warning/error messages.  Any ideas?

Thank you in advance,

J

Comment: Why not remove all up to last `_` including it? `sub(".*_", "", data_melt$variable)`. Well, you just need to replace `[A-z]` with `[A-Za-z]+`, and escape all dots, `.` => `\\.`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. A reminder to work smarter not harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might fix your approach by replacing `[A-z].` with `[A-Za-z]+\\.`:

```
data_melt$variable <- sub("D_0__[A-Za-z]+\\.D_1__[A-Za-z]+\\D_2__", "", data_melt$variable)
```

The `[A-z]` [matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926) and `.` matches any char, while you wanted to match a literal dot. When the dot is escaped, it only matches a literal dot.

However, you may solve the problem by removing all up to and including the last underscore:

```
sub(".*_", "", data_melt$variable)
```

Note you may use `sub` as you expect one replacement to be made.